# Qt / QTableView / SQLite how to connect?

Tags: sqlite, qt, qtableview

This is my first time Qt programming. I am to make an address book on relational database to keep track of calls and events, related to persons and companies. A simple home-made sales tool. I am in great need of it.

Using Qt Designer I have created a main window and placed a `QTableView` widget. Installed SQLite, created a database. Now I need to connect it to the `QTableView`. I spent several hours, and still couldn't do it.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Some code:

`untitled9.pro`:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-10-26T14:35:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += sql

TARGET = untitled9
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

`mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_menu_exit_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTableView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    QTableView *tableView;

    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_menu_exit_triggered()
{
  QCoreApplication::quit ();
}
```

And, there is also a long xml in mainwindow.ui. I'll post it here in case of need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [model-view related Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt/model-view-programming.html).

In general, you will need a [`QSqlTableModel`][2] which will correspond to a database table. Then you just need to attach it to a table view.

```
// Let a table A, with the following columns : id, column1, column2
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
model->setTable("A");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
model->removeColumn(0); // don't show the ID
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Column 1"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Column 2"));

// Attach it to the view
ui->view->setModel(model);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, pnezis! But this is not in fact the answer to my question. I was after a quick 'no-thinking' solution. I hoped that there was a standard datagrid functionality, allowing one to view/add/edit/delete records in a table. If there is a QTableView widget, there should be a quick way of connecting it to a table in a database. Am I wrong?

Comment: You just need to create the QSqlTableModel and set it to the view. Every change you make on the table will be propagated to the database. There is no simple way of doing this.

Comment: I see now that my question was not correct. It contains in fact two: 1. How to connect to DB. 2. How to connect a table to view.

Comment: I've got the idea, anyway. Thank you.